# Auto Re-sizing Windows form and its Tabs and its Controls in Tab Based on Resolution in VC# using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#

Good Day! I am using visual studio 2008. I have designed a Windows form in  c#. In that windows Form i have inserted one tab control, in this tab control i have 9 tabs. in these 9 tabs i have controls like label, text box, combo, etc..

Now i want to maximize windows form, tab control, controls in tab based on Resolution. In windows form property i changed window state to maximized. In this i getting only windows form maximized but i also want to maximize tab control and its controls. How to do it.

Can you please give me a suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some more information to your question. What relevant code do you have so far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dock or use the Anchor property. By setting Anchor to Left, Right, Top, Bottom the control will scale with the window.

Comment: Thanks Karthik. Yes as per your point tabcontrol only getting resized. But  tabs and controls in tabs are not resized. How to do this.